# How can I put classpath in property file while running java application?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have a java that I want to run with parameters and a classpath,
so I've created this startup script:

```
java -Denv=qa -Duser.timezone="GMT" -Dtest.services.mock=true -classpath ".;D:\\batch_server\\batch\\lib\\*;batch-server.jar" com.batch.servlet.StartBatch start
```

Which works very good.

Now I want to change the classpath to be written so that every jar file there will be written specifically e.g-

```
-classpath ".;D:\\batch_server\\batch\\lib\\log4j.jar;D:\\batch_server\\batch\\lib\\mokito.jar;  and so on
```

My question is can I puth the classpath in a property file so i can change it every time that I'm adding\removing a certain jar?

Comment: split the exeuction lines ie) classpath entry in one line and java exeution in second line so that you can alter it or parameterize the classpath variable.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Consider using a BAT file which collects all your jars and builds a classpath:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set CLASSPATH="
for /R ./lib %%a in (*.jar) do (
  set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%a
)
set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!"
echo !CLASSPATH!
```

Comment: This can work, but my classpath is to long to fit in a variabale.

so this solution can't work for me.

Comment: Too long? I think the max length of a variable is 32KB

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can write tour classpath into batch/shell scipt (depending on your platform). Since you are using `\` and `;` you are on windows, so batch file is relevant for you.

```
SET CP=log4j.jar
SET CP=%CP%;mkito.jar
.....
```

You can surely write jars into properties file too, but windows shell does not know this format, so you will have to write batch file that parses properties file format that is not so trivial but yet doable.

Other way to hold jars in properties file requires changing your application. You can create custom class loader that loads classes from jars mentioned in proprties file.

I am however not sure you really need this. Batch file IMHO is your solution.